# Caliburn.Micro - can I handle an action but continue to send it up the visual tree?

Tags: c#, silverlight, mvvm, caliburn.micro

So in the Caliburn.Micro MVVM framework, actions on objects in the visual tree will bubble up looking for a target. My question is, is it possible to handle these actions in a viewmodel, then allow them to continue to bubble up to find a second target?

Comment: too bad no one knows the answer here :( I'd love to know the answer too. I think we've to look into the RoutedEventArgs.Handled property. When calling an Action from XAML, you can send the RoutedEventArgs along as a parameter using [Event Click]=[Action MyMethod($eventArgs)]. I'm now trying to find out how you can prevent the first handler from setting the Handled property to "true" (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

Comment: It looks like it depends on what events you're working with.  For example:  A CheckBox will successfully bubble up the Checked and Unchecked events, but will mark the MouseDown event as handled and will then not bubbling up.  Still working through some problems with this myself

Answer (score 2):

Caliburn.Micro doesn't set the Handled Property to true when invoking an attached Action. So they should bubble up per default. Did you test this?